# Jquery hide/show on radio button selection

Tags: jquery, html

Just started playing with JQuery and have an issue which is driving me nuts. I'm sure its something completely obvious and simple but I haven't been able to solve it by following the already solved similar questions posted...

I'm simply trying to hide/show a section based on the selection of a Radio Button value..

My Html:

```
<div class="Packages">
              <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3><input id="Studio_PackageId" name="Studio.PackageId" type="radio" value="1" /> Option 1</h3>
                                <hr />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3><input id="Studio_PackageId" name="Studio.PackageId" type="radio" value="2" /> Option 2</h3>
                                <hr />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3><input id="Studio_PackageId" name="Studio.PackageId" type="radio" value="3" /> Option 3</h3>
                                <hr />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

My Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name$='Studio.PackageId']").click(function () {
        var ID = $(this).val();
        if (ID = 1) {
            $(".TrialSub").hide();
        } else {
            $(".TrialSub").show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The script is running but hides the section regardless of the Radio Button selected so I'm guessing the ID variable is not being set correctly but I'm not able to get it work.

Help is much appreciated...
TJ

Comment: you are missing == sigin in if(ID=1) it should be if(ID==1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `change` events instead of `click`.

You're using `=` and this is not an equal-operator. Use `==` if you want to check a variable for a value.

Comment: Legend... Thanks, I had already tried both but must have had something else wrong too.. all working now - thanks very much..

Answer (score 0):

you have given all of your inputs the same id (id="Studio_PackageId")
so whenever you click on an option, the selector is checking the value attribute of all input elements with id="Studio_PackageId".

instead you can use the selector to intercept a "click" on an *input* element:

```
$("input").click(function () {
    var ID = $(this).val();
    if (ID = 1) {
        $(".TrialSub").hide();
    } else {
        $(".TrialSub").show();
    }
});
```

in anycase, giving a uniqe ID value to each element will help you refering them, while still keeping them in the same 'family' of radio buttons (all have the same name value):

```
<input id="Studio_PackageId1" name="Studio.PackageId" type="radio" value="1" /> Option 1</h3>
<input id="Studio_PackageId2" name="Studio.PackageId" type="radio" value="1" /> Option 1</h3>
<input id="Studio_PackageId3" name="Studio.PackageId" type="radio" value="1" /> Option 1</h3>
```